# How to read file content with AsyncFileUpload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I want to read file content in AsyncFileUpload control:
I have used this markup:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="UpLoad_Button_Click" />
```

code behind:

```
  protected void UpLoad_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    
    string extention;
    extention=System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    
        
    if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile == true)
    {        
        if (extention == ".txt")
        {
        
            StreamReader readTextFile = new 
            StreamReader(AsyncFileUpload1.FileContent, Encoding.UTF8);
                                TextBox1.Text = readTextFile.ReadToEnd();
         }
       }
    }
```

I also put `AsyncFileUpload` outside of the `UpdatePanel` but when control changes to green `AsyncFileUpload` does not read txt file into TextBox1.

I also tried to use this code behind:

```
 protected void UpLoad_Button_Click(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        { ...}
```

instead of:

```
protected void UpLoad_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {...}
```

but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

You need to start grasping how a page lifecycle works. Without grasping the page lifecycle, you be coding in the dark forever.

You can't JUST assign any event to the async file upload control, but you must let vs and the editor create the events for you.

So, in the editor, WHEN you type in the OnUpLoadComplte=, then you MUST use the create event. or use the property sheet in the events tab, and double click on that event to create the event stub behind.

Since this is a async file up-load then NO post back occurs. It DOES NOT matter if you use a up-date panel, without a post-back, then code behind for that async method can NOT modify controls behind. That's was a ajax call to a web method on the page!

So, what this means?

You have to either save the file to some location or folder on the server, and THEN read the file.

I suppose another way would be save the text file content into session.

Since there is NOT a post-back, then no controls on the web page can be modified by that event stub.

But, the async file up-load DOES have the ability to trigger + run client side code after the upload is done. So, we could just drop a button into the update panel, and have JavaScript click on that button to run our code behind stub. Since now we have a post back (and YES a update panel does a post-back, including trigger of page load event), then we are now free to modify controls on the page, or in this case controls in the UP panel.

So, this code would work:

First the markup:

Note how we dropped in a button - and we hide it. That's going to post-back the update panel after the up-load, since as noted, the async file upload does NOT do a post back. And that includes EVEN when you place the async file upload inside of a update panel. For update panel code behind to update any control in that panel, you STILL need a post-back of that update panel.

So, this markup can be used:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server"
                    OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete"
                    OnClientUploadComplete="myclick" />

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="312px"
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="603px"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Button ID="cmdDonePostBack" runat="server" Text="post back button"
                    ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none"
                    OnClick="cmdDonePostBack_Click" />

                <script>
                    function myclick() {
                        $("#cmdDonePostBack").click()
                    }
                </script>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And now code behind is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string strText = "";

        StreamReader readTextFile = new StreamReader(AsyncFileUpload1.FileContent);
        strText = readTextFile.ReadToEnd();
        Session["MyText"] = strText;

    }

    protected void cmdDonePostBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Session["MyText"].ToString();
    }
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, note close, we let the up-load control up-load the file (no button click is required). We save the file text to session, since we can't touch or modify controls on that page (or in this case in the UP panel, since NO post-back has occurred, and thus the async file upload event can't touch controls or modify content on the page - that code stub actually runs as a ajax web method call, and thus no post-back occurred.

So, after the upload is complete, then we trigger the client side code and function. That function simple clicks on the hidden button, and then runs the code behind. But, as noted, we had to shove/save/tuck away the text file content some palace. The other alternative would be to save the text file on the server in some folder, and then read it back, or use session[] as per above.

We can't use browser viewstate, since that's browser based and requires a post back. And we can't modify any controls in that aj file upload, since the page has not been posted to the server for code behind to modify.

The other possible road would be to save text file to session (like above), and in place of a client side button click, you would call + use a page web method with ajax call, and that page web method would return the value of session as text. Then in client side, we modify the contents of that text box. This approach means the WHOLE process would work without a post-back, and in fact not even require a update panel, and no page post-back would be required.

So, a better approach would be this markup, and note how we don't need a update panel, and we don't need a hidden button either.

And we don't need a post back either.

so, this is a ajax solution here.

I assume you have jQuery installed.

So then this code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string strText = "";
        StreamReader readTextFile = new StreamReader(AsyncFileUpload1.FileContent);
        strText = readTextFile.ReadToEnd();
        Session["MyText"] = strText;
    }

    [WebMethod(enableSession:true)]
    public static string getmytext()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["MyText"].ToString();
    }
```

This markup:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server"
    OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete"
    OnClientUploadComplete="mydone" />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="312px"
    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="603px"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    ></asp:TextBox>

<script>
    function mydone() {
        var tb1 = $('#TextBox1')
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "FileUpLoadTest1.aspx/getmytext",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Data) {
                tb1.val(Data.d)
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

So, with above, we don't have a hidden button, we don't have a update panel, and we don't do any post-backs at all.

Comment: I have applied the Session tutorial it works fine, you explained it well so you are a great teacher... One thing is not working for me: I have tried to set the size of Width of the AsyncFileUpload control I have tried to reduce to 200px to have some room for the other buttons but its size remains around 800-1000px.  You also mentioned that ajaxtoolkit is free and I want to be sure if it can be used for commercial purposes so If I build it into my web project which I publish for commercial purposes is ajaxtoolkit still free?

Comment: Hum, setting the width of the AsyncFileUpLoad control should work. Say, using width="400px". And yes, the aj toolkit can be used in commercial applications without your code having to be open source.  Perhaps put the whole control in a div and size that width, and then remove the width from the aj File upload.